# How are Unicode objects represented in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

I've been doing a lot of reading about python Unicode encoding etcs and i think have a some understanding of it now. One final thing remains though.

Here is how i under stand it

In python 2.x the str object represents strings as bytes, depending on the encoding for these bytes we can get different characters. This is a simplification i know but for this question does not matter.

The unicode object however ive been told represents strings as unicode code points, so basically integers. No more ambiguously interpreting bytes into their values as we did before.

My question is how are these Unicode codepoints / integers represented under the hood in python, are they just 4 byte numbers regardless. Does this mean they use a lot more space than their str counterpart. Not that I'm worried about the space, I just want to understand.

Comment: read the Unicode tutorial: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CPython before 3.3, the text data in `unicode` objects is encoded as UCS-2 or UCS-4 (depending on a compile-time option) and stored in a `char*`. 3.3 uses a [variable representation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) for `unicode` data depending on the highest codepoint in the string. Jython and IronPython use their native types for `unicode` storage.

Comment: I doubt it was USC-2, as it could store code points outside the BMP (just as two "characters"). I guess that it was UTF-16, which is also what the CLR and JVM use.

Comment: maybe i understood the OP wrong, but I thought he asked about Python 2x, not 3x

Comment: @delnan: It really is UCS-2, which caused quite a few bugs when using non-BMP characters in a UCS-2 build.

Comment: @MichaelVayvala: 2.x < 3.3

Comment: So ultimately Unicode objects are still encoded as bytes but they use a completely universally accepted encoding system, which can still encode character efficiently?

Comment: @Luke1111: Yes, yes, not until 3.3.

Comment: @Luke1111 *Any* way to represent code points would constitute an encoding.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oh dear, you're right. Whose idea was that?

Comment: @Luke1111 the encoding can be 1, 2 or 4 bytes. UTF is expressed in serialized bits (UTF 8, 16, 32) and USC in machine bytes (UCS 1, 2, 4).